# Trying to set start time to previous completed time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check to see if the value for column 'complete' of is less than the startDate and if it is then I need to set the startDate to that value so the row is included in the return set....
]

In looking at the data set here:
[Data set and sample query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/24/0)

I have several things not working as I would like

1. row 12 isError should = 1 as row 12 and row 13 are both actiivtyID 1257
2. if row 10 is the FIRST row returned in a select statement (using a where date between start and end) I need to set the start date to row 10's completed value

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you just want a case statement in your select to return either/or on the dates?

Comment: For number 1 IF two consecutive rows are the same activityId then I need to set isError to 1 - the current code is checking based on sequential recordId's which is not going to work correctly because the check needs to be on sequential timestamped rows. So the question is how do i change this to check per row based on the timestamp and not the recordId sequence.

Comment: For number 2. If the first row returned was row 14 then I would like to set the 'startdate' in the 'where' portion of the query to equal the completed date seen in row 13 so is the where was where l1.completed between startDate and endDate - I would like to set startDate = row 13's completed

Comment: so query for number 2 would look something like SELECT ...
  FROM log1644 l1
     INNER JOIN log1644 t2
      ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
  WHere l1.completed between starDate and endDate
  ORDER BY l1.completed;

Comment: For number1, do you mean instead of using the recordid+1 as the t2 in your dataset do you want the next completed date to be t2?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: check my answer is that what you want? I am only selecting the recordId, and the time to show that it's sequenced correctly! then we can work on the rest of the other issues it should be easy

Comment: I still don't understand the part about `startdate` since i don't see any reference to `startdate` in your queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have many problems, let's solve it one step at a time.
First you want to have them sequenced using `completed` time so here's an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/49/0) that does that.

Next, we add `isError` [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/50/0)

Next, I cut and pasted your CoolingHours into it [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/51/0)

Next, I added logic for `rownum` [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/55/0)

Comment: Now I am stuck because I don't know what you mean about `startdate`

Comment: startDate is the date which is passed into the stored proc (it will be the variable that is the 'between startDate and endDate in the where clause

Comment: I simplified the query to try and help understand what I needed - now I am having trouble incorporating it into the from statement of  query - which is ... logs l 
       INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
       INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
       INNER JOIN log1644 l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId
       INNER JOIN log1644 t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
      WHERE i.itemID = 31985

Comment: I have gotten this far but it is giving me a cartesion ( I should return 25 rows - this is returning 87   [link]sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb50/56)